# Oracle : Error while Extracting Year and Month from TimeStamp

Tags: oracle, plsql, timestamp, to-date

I have time stamp values such as *`30/05/06 11:40:34.000000000 AM`* in the column. I need to extract Year (i.e. 2006) and the month (i.e. 05) from this value. Below is my SQL.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('19/10/09 10:45:44.000000000 AM')) FROM DUAL;
```

After running above SQL, I get an error `APPROVED_PROPOSALS`.

So, I tried to provide the format as below,

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('19/10/09 10:45:44.000000000 AM','HH12:MI:SS.FF')) FROM DUAL;
```

However, still getting some errors. I am pretty sure that, the format I am providing is not correct.

> `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

Please help me, to get Year and Month form such values.

Kiran.

Comment: Why are you using string in your query, instead of extracting directly from the column which is of the timestamp data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to use timestamp column in your query you won't have problems you mentioned (this example is based on Nitish's answer):

```
with t as
(
  select to_timestamp('19/10/2009 10:45:44.000000000 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss.ff9 am') ts
    from dual
)
select extract(year from ts) ts_year,
       extract(month from ts) ts_month
  from t;
```

Additionally I would suggest you to check if fractional seconds are stored in this column, since in your examples they are not. This usually means that you are inserting sysdate in this column, instead of systimestamp. If fractional seconds are not needed there is no point in having timestamp column - date type would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT EXTRACT (
      YEAR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP ('19/10/09 10:45:44.000000000 AM',
                              'DD/MM/YY HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM'))
FROM DUAL;
```

This is assuming year comes after month. In the format part, you need to give the format of date too, not just time part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is you don't specify 'dd/mm/yy' in your date format. And as Nitish points out, you have a timestamp (more accurate), not a date.

You should use correct format, as follows:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('19/10/09 10:45:44.00000 AM', 'dd/mm/yy HH12:MI:SSXFF PM')) FROM DUAL;
```

Or us fixed determination:

```
select substr('19/10/09 10:45:44.00000 AM', 4,2) MONTH 
     , substr('19/10/09 10:45:44.00000 AM', 7,2) YEAR
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. It was a great help, appreciate it . I used the following queries,

1. Get year :

   select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP 
   ('15/10/09 11:07:28.999900 AM', 'DD/YY/MM HH:MI:SS.FF a.m.'),'DD/YY/MM HH24:MI:SS'),
   'DD/YY/MM HH24:MI:SS'))) DT
   FROM DUAL;
2. Month

   select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP 
   ('15/10/09 11:07:28.999900 AM', 'DD/YY/MM HH:MI:SS.FF a.m.'),'DD/YY/MM HH24:MI:SS'),
   'DD/YY/MM HH24:MI:SS'))) DT
   FROM DUAL;